# For untracked file I get error: Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches

Tags: git, checkout

```
kes@work ~/c $ git status
On branch fix_typos_and_do_small_improvements
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   dancer/_global/t/lib/Global/Test/Routes.pm

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    Utils.pm

kes@work ~/c $ git checkout check_responses_from_backend
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    dancer/_global/t/lib/Global/Test/Routes.pm
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

I know, I did changes at my working directory and before switching branches I should stash my changes. I did that and that works well, but not now.
Here I create file at my current working directory and I do not want to lose these changes. It is new for current branch, but this file already exists at the branch I want to switch to.

Why I can not switch to different branch? I do not see any problem that that could not be done. Please explain what is happened here. Thank you.

** git version 2.35.3

Comment: to be clear, why does stashing not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I can not switch to different branch?

You have a file that, in *your* working tree and *your current branch*, is *untracked*.  (This file is named `dancer/_global/t/lib/Global/Test/Routes.pm`.)

That other branch name `check_responses_from_backend` selects a commit in which this same file *is tracked and committed*.<sup>1</sup>  In order to switch *to* that branch, Git *must overwrite your current version of the file*.

Git is telling you exactly this.  Git is saying: *If I do what you asked, you will lose the contents of your file.  PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE **SAVE** THOSE CONTENTS and if you fail to do that don't blame me!*

The *easiest* way to deal with this is for you to *save the contents of that file* by making it tracked and committing, or by moving it to some other name, possibly entirely out of your working tree.  You can then switch to that other branch, because the file's contents are safely saved away under some other name or in some commit.  When you want those contents back later, you get them from that other name, or from the commit you made.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, it's just "committed": the tracked-ness of the file depends on the action that happens during your `git checkout` or `git switch`.  But if you successfully check out that branch, you'll have a tracked file, which will have the contents from that commit.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. If file on my source branch has been tracked and changed I just `git add <file>` and then switch. Why this does not work for untracked? Notice, I did **git add** : `Changes to be committed: new file:   dancer/_global/t/lib/Global/Test/Routes.pm`. So content of my untracked file is saved. Now it is safe to switching to new branch. And after that saved content could be applied without problem. Probably should be some flag like `--autostash` for git rebase, but for `git checkout`? 2. `or by moving it to some other name` that is not possible if there are >20+ files.Too hard

Comment: Until you *commit* the file, the previously-untracked file isn't actually saved anywhere. Just `git add` alone is not sufficient. (There is no autostash for checkout; there's no obvious point where it would un-stash, unlike rebase which un-stashes when the rebase finishes.)

Comment: Why there is not obvious point? I think that should be done after checkout is done. 1. I `git add` file. 2. `git checkout --autostash newbranch` 3. after switching apply saved stash. Which problem could happened if that option will be implemented?

Comment: Let's say that you're on commit `a123456` when you make the stash. You switch from branch `hello` to branch `world` which selects commit `b789abc`. Then you rename branch `hello` to branch `hi`, and check out commit `a123456` via branch name `dev`. Should the stash made on `hello` be applied at the time you switch to `world`? What about when you switch to branch name `dev` or branch name `hi`?

Comment: 1. I am on `a123` 2. I mark untracked file `git add <file1>` 3. `git checkout --autostash world` 4. marked file is saved into stash, branch is switched to world, stash is restored. First answer: yes, because I provide `git checkout --autostash`. So now I am on `world` and <file1> has changes. If I just switch `git checkout hi` then everything works as usual. If I `git checkout --autostash hi` then: 1. changes are saved into stash 2. hi branch is checked out 3. stash is applied (poped) but because we lack file1 on `hi` the full copy checkedout from `world` and stash is applied.

Comment: Feel free to propose this to the Git mailing list.

Comment: From you point of view, will that work?

Comment: I personally doubt it. I dislike *all* the autostash options though; I think none of them should ever have been implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You can. You just have to use the flag `-f` but it will cause the unstaged file to be overwritten by what comes from the destination branch. This is not normally wanted so you have to explicitly say so.

Comment: I know that option. I do not want to lose changes at untracked file